# Create Unique Constraint based on Start Date and End Date

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

I created a unique constraint as below which is working fine. But I want to create a constraint where the productNumber between the two dates should be unique

```
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product]  ADD CONSTRAINT  U_Product UNIQUE ([ProductNumber],[StartDate],[EndDate])
```

Right now, it is taking the exact value in columns, but I want it between two dates. How can I do this ?

[image: table]

Comment: I don't think this is possible with SQL Server (btw: why are you posting a screenshot of a text result? Doesn't make sense. Adding the example data as text only would have been much easier I think)

Comment: You could do it with either a Trigger or a Check Constraint that checks a UDF.

Comment: @TabAlleman How is it possible using a Check Constraint? How would you get the values of the expected inserted \ updated data to the function?

Comment: create an unique filtered index `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX whatever 
ON Product (ProductNumber)
WHERE startdate >= '2015-01-01'
  and startdate <= '2015-02-01';`

Comment: @ZoharPeled You use a field name as a parameter in the function.   Here is a simple explanation/example:  http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/using-udf-check-constraint-validate-column

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks, I didn't know it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
create function dbo.IsProductUnique (@ProductNumber int, @StartDate date, @EndDate date) returns bit as
begin
  if exists (
    select *
    from Product
    where ProductNumber = @ProductNumber
      and StartDate < @EndDate
      and EndDate > @StartDate) return 0
  else 
    return 1 -- Unique
end
go

alter table Product add constraint CK_Product_Unique check (dbo.IsProductUnique(ProductNumber, StartDate, EndDate) = 1)
go
```